# Crash on missing hdpi resources

Tags: android

I have an odd situation. I have an app that was targeted to run on devices with maximum mdpi pixel density. For that reasons the hdpi and higher resources are stripped from the apk. Now we have a new device with higher dpi settings that would set it to hdpi. My expectation is that the lower res assets would simply be blown up. However I get the error below:
Any ideas ? I have even tried creating a drawable directory with a copy of the mdpi icons but no joy, still the same crash.

Edit 3: The method used to remove the hdpi and xhdpi removes the resources from the apk by calling 'aapt r filename'. Later the app is re-sign and re-aligned but I think references to the removed resources stay there. When I remove the resources from the build tree, that is, before building the apk, all works fine.

Edit: I've tried building my app including the Hdpi resources and it works fine those in. Problem is that I can afford having such heavy resources in.

Edit 2: below the snippet that causes the crash

```
public class MyCustomButton extends Button {
...
 public MyCustomButton(ControlContext controlContext, Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialise(controlContext, context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

crash happens on the call to super.

```
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.HostActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.mycompany.controlslib.view.ListExpanded
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.mycompany.controlslib.view.ListExpanded
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-01 00:06:10.220 E/AndroidRuntime(  809):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
```

Comment: what make's you think this has anything to do with mdpi vs. hdpi? I don't see anything in the stacktrace that'd imply that. is there more to the stack trace?

Comment: Looks more like an issue with your custom widget class.

Comment: It would be better if we could see some code...

Comment: put some default resources in drawable folder

Comment: @njzk2 I've already tried that. Same behavior.

Comment: what is your device ?

Comment: @AndroidWarrior will add some cleaned-up, meaning no reference to my boss, later in the day. Though I gotta say the crash happens when, on my custom control's constructor, we invoke the super(), the 3 arguments version, for the construction of the standard button control.

Comment: @njzk2 it's our own device.

Comment: I dont see the cause of this error due to missing of some resources.You probably might not be inflating your layout properly.Could you post more of your code for the problem to be identified.

Comment: @user3005612 Your error is most probably in inflating your XML, Post some more code for better understanding.

Comment: I added Edit 3. Basically I think my problem is that with the current way of removing resources, simply by doing the 'aapt remove' on the files in the apk, there are still references to those files, don't know where that stay. So the question becomes, how do I keep the consistency after removing the files on the apk ?